# How to check if user input does not correspond to what I need?

Tags: java

How to check if user input does not correspond to what I need ?
in the code below, if my user answer 3 or nothing or anything other than oui/non, it still works... and even so when they type in nuts, it works for the "non"...
I just want the program to work if my user answer oui or non

```
    public static short count;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        hasKey();
    }

    public static void hasKey (){
        System.out.print("\nEst-ce que vous avez vos clé ? (oui/non)");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String answer = scan.nextLine();
        boolean aSesClés =  answer.toLowerCase().startsWith("o"); ;
        if (aSesClés) {
            System.out.println("\nVous avez vos clés !");
        } else if (count == 10) {
            System.out.println("\nVous avez perdu vos clés !");
        } else {
            whichPlace();
        }
    }

    public static void whichPlace() {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("\nQuel endroit ? ");
        String quelEndroit= sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("\nvous avez choisi : "+quelEndroit);
        count++;
        hasKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Very beginner here

Comment: `boolean aSesClés =  answer.toLowerCase().startsWith("o"); ;` why don't you actually check whether the input equals to "oui", instead? If you don't, "ordinateur" would be a valid answer for "oui".

Comment: Just check for `"oui".equalsIgnoreCase(answer)` and `"non".equalsIgnoreCase(answer)`  and if neither matches, ask again.

Comment: This document is pretty helpful: https://codehs.gitbooks.io/introcs/content/Basic-JavaScript-and-Graphics/loop-and-a-half.html

Answer (score 0):

You can add a loop that will run until the user types in the right thing:

```java
final Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

String answer;

// A loop that will run undefinitely
for (;;) {
    System.out.print("\nEst-ce que vous avez vos clé ? (oui/non)");
    answer = scan.nextLine();
    if (answer.equals("oui") || answer.equals("non")) {
        // Exit the loop and proceed with your logic
        break;
    }
    // Otherwise, proceed with the loop
    System.out.println("Invalid answer!");
}

// Your logic when the user types a valid `answer`
```